# S3 Upload with Secret Key (react-dropzone-uploader)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

(UPDATED: See Below) I am implementing the [react-dropzone-uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/) into my React project and so far it has been awesome to work with and customize.  I am wanting these uploads to POST to my S3 bucket.

The documentation [HERE](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/s3) gives me an example of how to do this using a `presigned upload url`.  I was able to authenticate with the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` (last code snippet below), however I am unsure how to get the *dropzone* logic to upload properly.

---

Here's one of the package's default functions:

```
const Standard = () => {
  const getUploadParams = () => {
    return { url: 'https://httpbin.org/post' }
  }

  const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta }, status) => {
    console.log(status, meta)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
    allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      styles={{ dropzone: { minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 250 } }}
    />
  )
}

<Standard />
```

... and here is the documentation-suggested implementation of calling an API that returns the pre-signed AWS S3 url (validates credentials):

```
const getUploadParams = async ({ meta: { name } }) => {
  const { fields, uploadUrl, fileUrl } = await myApiService.getPresignedUploadParams(name)
  return { fields, meta: { fileUrl }, url: uploadUrl }
}
```

---

(UPDATES:)
Okay, I was able to get my connection to S3 working with the following code living in a `authAWS.js` file:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  accessKeyId: '<access_key>',
  secretAccessKey: '<secret_key>'
})

export const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: 'BUCKETNAME'
  },
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
});

export const list_ = s3.listObjects({Delimiter: '/invoice/'}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return alert('There was an error listing your objects: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getUploadParams = async ({ meta }) => {
    try {
        console.log(meta);
        const { name, type } = meta;
        const res = await axios.get('/s3/sign', {
            params: {
                fileName: name,
                contentType: type
            },
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://localhost:3000",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                "content-type": type
            }
        }
        );
        console.log(res)
        return res.data.signedUrl;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I have this function to get URL from S3 Bucket, but they throw a CORS problems error.

I hope it will help you.